# Deep Security 12 - update agent via API

Tags: deepsecurity

Is it possible to update Deep Security Agents via API call? Or are there other automation possibilities regarding updates?

If not, when this would be possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seba - Thanks for the question...

I work in the product team for Deep Security.  The quick answer is that we currently don’t have API support for upgrading agents today.  This is something in our backlog, but I don’t have an ETA that can be shared at this time.

What I would suggest on a topic like this is to look at how other software on your servers is managed and try to leverage the tooling and processes that is common with other applications.  For example, this could be management tools like BigFix/SCCM or automation tools like Jenkins/Chef.  Rather than having to develop and manage something specific to upgrade the Deep Security Agent aligning what is done for other software on your servers can save you some time/effort.

If you have not seen this before we have some information here that might be helpful as well:

https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/agent-upgrade.html

Hope that helps…